# How to create and bind a GridView where the columns are determined by a database table?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'd like to create a GridView (preferably telerik) where the columns are generated and bound based on rows in the database. The grid should look like this:
[image]

Here is an example of what the database setup is.
I have 3 database tables as follows:

Employees - A list of Employee Names

States- A list of States

EmployeeStates- join table, which has an EmployeeID, StateID, and boolean for checked or unchecked.

New rows can be added to both database tables so that the list of employees and list of cities will get longer.
How do I bound this to a GridView?

Comment: Have you actually tried going to the telerik website and searching their docs?  They also have demo and such.

Comment: I will have a look there. However, Is this specific to Telerik? I would think it should be possible with any GridView?

Comment: since your comment was "preferably Telerik" then yes it would be specific to Telerik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you still have this issue, but we solved it a while back. It wasn't straightforward, but can be done. Our tables were for treatment sites (parts of the body) and treatment types, and we wanted to display a grid showing all the possible sites, along with the ones ticked for the patient in question.

The server-side query to get the data looked like this...

```
int systemID = 210;
var cross = TreatmentSites.Select(ts => new {
  TreatmentSiteID = ts.ID,
  TreatmentSiteName = ts.Description,
  Checked = string
    .Join("", TreatmentCheckTypes
              .OrderBy(tct => tct.ID)
              .Select(cs => SystemTreatmentSitesCheckeds
                .Any(s => s.Active
                       && s.SystemID == systemID
                       && s.TreatmentSiteID == ts.ID
                       && s.TreatmentCheckTypeID == cs.ID) ? "y" : "n"))
})
.ToArray();
```

This pulled out a list of sites, with a string of the form `nnyyn` for the types that were checked.

Nest job was to massage that into something that could be used by WPF. For that, we used the following code...

```
Dictionary<String, dynamic>[] data = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>[cross.Count()];
for (int crossN = 0; crossN < cross.Count(); crossN++) {
  var d = new Dictionary<String, dynamic>();
  d["TreatmentSiteID"] = cross[crossN].TreatmentSiteID;
  d["TreatmentSiteName"] = cross[crossN].TreatmentSiteName;
  for (int checktypeN = 0; checktypeN < treatmentCheckTypes.Count(); checktypeN++) {
    d["C" + checktypeN] = cross[crossN].Checked[checktypeN] == 'y';
  }
  data[crossN] = d;
}
```

That gave us the data we needed. With that, the WPF view was able to add columns to the grid in code, then bind the data to the grid.

The above is the basic idea. More details of how it works can be [found on my blog](http://www.pixata.co.uk/2017/07/18/what-to-do-when-the-columns-in-a-query-are-to-be-determined-dynamically/).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow this [link](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/integration-with-other-telerik-products/telerikui-for-wpf/developer-guide-integr-telerik-products-wpf-bind-data)  You should have enough examples to get some idea.  Think points to the WPF telerik components.

Answer (score 0):

You could set or bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `RadGridView` to an `IEnumerable<YourType>` where your `YourType` is a class that has the Employee, NJ, PA, RI and NY properties.

Or to a `DataView` of a `DataTable`.

You will have to write an SQL query that selects the appropriate data from the database and then create an instance of `YourType` for each returned record, or use the `DataTable` directly. There are plenty of example of how to communicate with a database available online:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How can I define the YourType class if each time it will have need different properties? It's true that initially it will only need Employee, NJ, PA, RI, and NY, but with time there will be more.

Comment: You could bind the ItemsSource directly to the DataView of a DataTable. See my edit. Then you don't have to create any custom type.

Comment: How do I use a DataTable if I'm  using Entity Framework?

Comment: Just create one and add a DataColumn per property you want to display in the DataGrid as I explained in my answer.

Comment: But please ask another question if you have another issue. Your original question has nothing to do with EF. You asked on how to display data in a DataGrid.